# Creating android application for checking health of mysql databse

Tags: android, mysql, database-performance

I want to create a android application which will check the health of database, hence I can check status of database from mobile,
I'm using mysql database.
Could you please suggest some architecture which will help full in checking the status of database.

I'm going to develop in native android and backend is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Client -> Web Application (PHP) -> Check connecting to database -> Echo result in JSON